# Error unexpected token when posting JSON string to JSP

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jsp, post

Here's my code:

```
var polylineStringified = JSON.stringify(polyPath.getArray());

$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'jsonposttest.jsp',
        data: { Polyline: polylineStringified },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            alert('json from post test: ' + JSON.stringify(json));
        }, error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){ 
             alert('Error xhr : ' + xhr.status); 
            alert('Error thrown error: ' + thrownError); 
        }

});
```

And serverside:

```
<%

String test;
test = getRequest(pageContext, "Polyline");

response.setContentType("application/json");

%>

[
 {"val": "Got it: <%=test%>" }
]
```

polylineStringified looks something like this:

```
[{"d":41.919372021888826,"e":-87.69811456091702},{"d":41.90506457136218,"e":-87.23119561560452},{"d":41.80277524389252,"e":-87.23668877966702},{"d":41.74747099702249,"e":-87.35479180701077}]
```

And the error I'm getting in the console is is unexpected token d. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the error occur before or after the `$.ajax` call?

Comment: @iX3 how can I tell? The error is caught in the error: function(... of the ajax call..

Comment: For the purposes of my question that means it did not occur before, so it occurred during/after.

Comment: What does the console produce if you add `console.log({ Polyline: polyPath.getArray() });` before the `$.ajax` call?

Comment: @iX3 Console produces...

Polyline: Array[3]
0: Q
d: 41.89484300040747
e: -87.84914535004646
__proto__: Q
1: Q
2: Q
length: 3
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object

Comment: `Q`?? Sounds like you have some kind of additional object information here. Perhaps you should try extracting just the parts you want to send (`d` and `e` properties) and copying them to a new object just to help isolate your problem.

Comment: I supposed you could try doing `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))`, but that seems awfully sloppy/wasteful.

Comment: @iX3 JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...)) yields the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are unnecessarily stringifying your javascript object. What happens if you use the following?

```
var polylineArray = [{
    "d": 41.919372021888826,
    "e": -87.69811456091702
}, {
    "d": 41.90506457136218,
    "e": -87.23119561560452
}, {
    "d": 41.80277524389252,
    "e": -87.23668877966702
}, {
    "d": 41.74747099702249,
    "e": -87.35479180701077
}];

$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'jsonposttest.jsp',
        data: { Polyline: polylineArray },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            alert('json from post test: ' + JSON.stringify(json));
        }, error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){ 
             alert('Error xhr : ' + xhr.status); 
            alert('Error thrown error: ' + thrownError); 
        }
});
```

### EDIT: Here's another example, which you can try at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/quant/ynTvL/).

It should be quite straightforward, so you can compare it to yours at each step to find what is wrong in your situation.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var Q = function (d, e) {
        this.d = d;
        this.e = e;
    }
    var data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var r1 = 100 * (2*Math.random() - 1);
        var r2 = 100 * (2*Math.random() - 1);
        data.push(new Q(r1, r2));
    }
    console.log("About to send data", data);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/echo/json/',
        data: {
            Polyline: data
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        //processData: false,
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log("success", data, textStatus, jqXHR);
            //alert('json from post test: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log("error", xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError);            
            //alert('Error xhr : ' + xhr.status);
            //alert('Error thrown error: ' + thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: That works, but when I undo the stringify and just pass it it doesn't like it. Says function undefined lat or something, like it's trying to access the object or something

Comment: It comes back from the server as null

Comment: So that seems to suggest that your problem lies with how you are preparing your JSON data to send. I would recommend familiarizing yourself with some of the options to `jQuery.ajax`, in particular the `processData` option, which is `true` by default. Basically, you should be passing a regular object to `jQuery.ajax` and not a stringified version -- jQuery will take care of it for you. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/